# Can't scan with Samsung SCX-4216F

Tags: printer, scanner, multi-function-printer

I Have Samsung SCX-4216F multifunctional printer connected via LPT port to Windows XP machine. I have installed printing and scanning drivers from Samsung and software called SmartThru 3. Unfortunately when I trying to scan I have errors like:

```
Samsung TWAIN for Scan
Port is Disabled.Ensure that port is properly connected and power is on, Then restart your computer.
```

How to make scanner work on this device?

Comment: Can you print?
Is there any firewall/antivirus software enabled on your machine? If so, pls try disabling and test again.

Comment: it is connected via LPT port - no need to disable firewall. Yes, it can print

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with bidirectional parallel port support being dropped at some point. Can't remember if this was with XP, I haven't had parallel port gear in a while.

Comment: According to the OEM manual Troubleshooter: "The printer cable may be improperly connected or the power may be off. You must use a parallel cable that supports IEEE-1284 bi-directional communications." Are you using the correct cable? Also, there is no mention for an OS requirement for that connector, only the USB.